# Brew not updating to latest GCC-ARM

Tags: gcc, arm, homebrew

I'm trying to upgrade my gcc-arm install to the latest version (4.9/20150609), but brew keeps thinking 4.8 is the latest.

I've run:

```
brew up
brew update
brew doctor
brew upgrade gcc-arm-none-eabi
brew cleanup
```

when I run `brew upgrade gcc-arm-none-eabi`, I get the following error:

```
Error: px4/px4/gcc-arm-none-eabi 20140805 already installed
```

when I run `arm-none-eabi-gcc --version`, I get the following:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.8.4 20140725
```

So how do I get brew to install the latest version of gcc-arm-none-eabi?  I need 4.9.

Answer (score 0):

gcc-arm-none-eabi-49 is likely what you're looking for:

```
brew uninstall gcc-arm-none-eabi
brew cleanup
brew install gcc-arm-none-eabi-49
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question/page looking for help installing the `gcc-arm-none-eabi` toolchain from scratch using Homebrew, you can find instructions for installing from scratch in the [`homebrew-armeabi`](https://github.com/eblot/homebrew-armeabi) repository on Github.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew cask instal gcc-arm-embedded
```